# What is the cart and cable connected to this plane?

Tags: ground-operations

During boarding I noticed many times that planes are "connected" with some orange cable.

[image]

It's curious to know what is it. Does anybody knows?

Comment: The "Vote to Close" presumes that the answer to the other question is in fact the correct answer to this question, and while that might be the case, it's not clear to me that it necessarily is.  The cart in this picture looks entirely different than the cart in the "duplicated" question, and the cable is much, much longer in this picture. Voting to leave open, at least until something more definitive than voting-to-close shows that the answers are, in fact, the same.

Comment: @RalphJ technically it can be answered each time, as there are many cables which get connected to an aircraft during ground ops, and the photo in thus question depicts a different aircraft to the one in the linked question... they are both ground power, just in this case the cable isnt connected to a power source, and are bundled on some steps.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On further investigation, thats an A320 rather than a 757, and the [A320 Airport and Maintenance Planning document](http://www.airbus.com/fileadmin/media_gallery/files/tech_data/AC/Airbus_AC_A320_Jun16.pdf) shows that that hookup is the ground power port (page 206).

The stairs are for passing documentation up to the cockpit side windows, which open.